# ¿Quién es el sujeto en la frase "hay alguien"?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis, sujeto

¿Es "alguien" el sujeto de esta frase? ¿Puede el sujeto venir después del verbo?

Comment: En español, en cualquier parte de la oración colocar el sujeto puedes tú, joven jedi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La pregunta debería haber sido: ¿**Cuál / Qué palabra/frase** es el sujeto en la **oración** "Hay alguien"? El sujeto es una función sintáctica, no una persona a la que nos podamos referir a través del pronombre "quién". Además, "Hay alguien" no es una frase, sino una oración.

La respuesta es que la oración no tiene sujeto, pues cuando "haber" tiene el sentido de "existir" es impersonal y, por lo tanto, carece de sujeto. Prueba de esto es que, en otras formas del verbo, éste no toma el número del sustantivo plural que sigue: *Había (NO "Habían") muchas personas ahí.*

Según el punto 15.3.1 de la Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española, se trata de la variante locativa:

> **15.3.1 Construcciones con HABER IMPERSONAL**
>
> **15.3.1a** Admiten estas construcciones dos variantes, una locativa y otra adscriptiva. En la primera, la noción de 'presentación' se combina con la de 'localización', a veces implícita, como en *¿Hay alguien?*, donde el argumento locativo se interpreta deícticamente: *¿Hay alguien ahí?*, o en *Hay novedades*, donde se recupera a través del contexto o la situación.

En realidad, en las construcciones con "*haber* impersonal" lo que sigue no es sujeto sino objeto directo (OD). Si bien con "alguien" la prueba de reemplazar el OD por un pronombre "lo/a/s" no funciona (simplemente porque "alguien" es indefinido), sí funciona cuando lo que sigue es un OD definido: *Hay novedades -> **Las** hay.*

Comment: Creo entender lo que dices, si con "el sujeto es una funcion sintactica" quieres decir que " es el elemento de la oración que concuerda en número y persona con el verbo "  pero me parece que la definicion de "sujeto" de español no coincide con la de otras lenguas . Puede ser esto asi? Honestamente me quedaria con otra definicion, sirve mas para entender un idioma.

Comment: @Pablo En los idiomas que conozco, el "sujeto" debe coincidir en número y persona con el verbo. En portugués, "muitas pessoas" no es sujeto en la oración "Tem muitas pessoas", porque "tem" es singular y "muitas pessoas" es plural. En inglés, hay un sujeto gramatical y un sujeto lógico o real en "Is there anybody?" ("there" es el sujeto gramatical, y "anybody" el sujeto lógico). En inglés, "anybody" ("alguien") es sujeto porque hay concordancia con el verbo. De hecho, el verbo cambia si se usa un sujeto en plural: ***Are** there any **people** ...?*

Comment: en japonés los verbos no se ven afectados por el número y la persona del sujeto

Comment: @Pablo Cada lengua tiene su gramática, y no podemos aplicar los conceptos gramaticales de una lengua a otra. En español "haber" es impersonal porque no denota un estado o acción atribuible a un sujeto. Compara, por ejemplo: "Hubo muchos accidentes" y "Ocurrieron muchos accidentes". Si bien el significado es similar, la gramática española indica que "muchos accidentes" no es sujeto (si lo fuera, se diría "hubieron"). Observa que podemos decir: "Muchos accidentes ocurrieron" pero no "Muchos accidentes hubo", al igual que podemos decir "Los hubo" pero no "Los ocurrieron".

Answer (score 1):

Es un bonito rompecabezas sintáctico.

De primera mano se antoja responder que el sujeto siempre es quien realiza o ejerce la acción del verbo, luego **alguien** es el sujeto. Lo que lleva a un argumento recursivo en un chusco juego de palabras. (Quién es el sujeto? -Alguien -pues si, pero quién?)

El problema es que se trata de un verbo transitivo (ser/estar) y requiere de otro verbo para transmitir la acción a **"alguien"** que en realidad es el objeto directo, en quién recae la acción del verbo.

Podríamos suponer que se trata de un sujeto tácito o implícito, sin embargo no hay suficiente contexto en la oración para construirlo o derivarlo.

Luego, lo que tenemos aquí, es un **fragmento de enunciado** no hay sujeto, estrictamente hablando.

Es fuerte la tentación sin embargo, de construir ese contexto tratando de dar sentido al fragmento, por ejemplo en la frase idiomática *"hay alguien ahí?"* Que siendo un fragmento de oración, se reconoce universalmente como una pregunta *"al aire"* tratando de determinar si uno se encuentra solo o en compañía de otra persona, más allá de lo que nuestros sentidos nos permiten dilucidar.

Otra forma de expresarse la misma *pregunta al aire* es *quién vive?*